# I want to do full CURD operation in JQuery Datatable for SharePoint List item

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, datatable

I want to have Add, Edit, Delete options of Jquery datatable for my SharePoint list item. Have anyone implemented this.

I know how to show data in datatable using SharePoint REST, But facing challenges in ful CURD operation.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following articles with source code for your reference.

[**Using jQuery DataTable To Display SharePoint 2013 List Data On SharePoint Site Pages**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-jquery-datatable-to-display-sharepoint-list-data-on-share/)

[**CRUD Operations In SharePoint REST API Using jQuery AJAX**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-api-using-jquery-ajax/)

[**DataTables example-REST interface**](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/REST.html)